# How to display row like "No record found" if datasource is empty - angular/ material2

Tags: angular

I am using angular/material2 for displaying table.

```
 <mat-table class="table" #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >    
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{col}}" *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{col | camelize}} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <div *ngIf="col!=='actions'"> {{element[col]}} </div>
            <div *ngIf="col==='actions'"> <a (click)="viewDetails(element.id)">View</a> </div>                
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
<div ><mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row></div>
```

if [dataSource] is empty, how to display row as "No record found", now its display only the headers of the table.

Comment: Add another div with the message and use *ngIf

Comment: i tried but it's not working because if datasource is empty, <mat-cell> is not created

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show empty message in data table angular material, If no data found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149632/how-to-show-empty-message-in-data-table-angular-material-if-no-data-found)

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find a conical way to do that, but here is my workaround :

In your dataSource you should add a catch on the observable returned by you connect method :

```
connect() { return #YourObservable#.catch(err => Observable.of(<any>([{ error: 'No results'}]))) }
```

on your table template add the column définition ( the ngClass displayed is needed cause the error column will always be added to DOM even )

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="error">
        <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef class="error"></mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let item" class="error" [ngClass]="{displayed: item.error}">
            {{ item.error}}
        </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

**/!\ Add the error column to the displayed columns /!**

and in the css had some rules so that error column dont break your display when no error :

```
mat-table .error {
    flex: 1 0 100%; // <- to the error while take all the rows
    text-align: center; // <- cause its pretty
    color:red; // <- cause red errors are so neat

    &:not(.displayed) {
        display: none; // <- only way for me to do that
    }
}
```

NB: Of better solution should be to register a callback in your dataSource which should be called on error. Then in this callback you could update the displayedColumns of your mat-table.

Hope it helps !