# How to show empty message in data table angular material, If no data found

Tags: angular

I am using this code

```
 <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >
  <ng-container matColumnDef="tache">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> tâche </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.tache}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="outil">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> outil </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.outil}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
  </mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

So, how to show empty message "No Record found" in data table.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by data not found?

Comment: If datasource is empty I have to display 'No records found message'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's like bugs is saying, you can just use `*ngIf`. Compare these two tables here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9ckf8

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">My empty table</mat-toolbar>

<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSourceEmpty" matSort *ngIf="dataSourceEmpty.length > 0">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Age">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Age </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="row.toggle(row)">
    </mat-row>
</mat-table>

<div *ngIf="dataSourceEmpty.length === 0">No records found</div>

<hr>

<mat-toolbar color="primary">My full table</mat-toolbar>

<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort *ngIf="dataSource.length > 0">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Age">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Age </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="row.toggle(row)">
    </mat-row>
</mat-table>

<div *ngIf="dataSource.length === 0">No data</div>
```

> TS with data:

```
displayedColumns = ['Name', 'Age']
dataSource = [{name:'Sara',age:17}, {name: 'John', age: 20}]
dataSourceEmpty = []
```

Comment: thx i fixed it with <mat-toolbar color="primary" *ngIf="empty">No records found message</mat-toolbar>

Comment: Cool, glad I could help

Comment: The example relies on a simple datasource that is a JS array. What do you recommend when using an instance of abstract class DataSource<T> that Angular provides in @angular/cdk/collections/typings/data-source.d.ts ?

Comment: You will get an undefined error when you try to set dataSource.sort = matSort, since @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort; will be undefined until the table is available.  If you remove the matSort directive from the table, this would be ok.

You could also put your put your table inside another component and handle the "no results" in the parent component, so that the table, datasource, and matsort are all initiated at once IF there is data.

Comment: I'm desperately looking for an answer to the same question @chrisinmtown asked above.  How can one access the underlying raw data (or at minimum a record count of the data) in a CDK datasource???  I've scoured the internet for hours with no luck... please help!!

Comment: @DerekWohlfahrt my datasource defines a public variable rowCount and sets its value in the method that subscribes to the service method that fetches data. Then I use a condition in the HTML template like this: "dataSource.rowCount > 0". HTH

Comment: If your initial dataset is empty, using an `*ngIf` on the table breaks the `MatSort` because when you try to bind the viewchild in your controller, it won't exist because the table isn't being rendered. So if you then load data into the table, it will display, but sorting will not work because the `MatSort` did not get initialized properly. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: that approach looks bad if the table has horizontal scrollbar

Comment: We want the columns

Comment: @LeonardoRick If you want to keep the columns, remove the line `*ngIf="dataSourceEmpty.length > 0"` on line 8 in my example.

Answer (score 113):

With **Angular Material 10 or above** If you want to show a message when not data matches the filter, you can use the *matNoDataRow directive.

```
 <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
  <td class="mat-cell" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
    No data matching the filter.
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If using `<mat-table>` instead of a `<table>` then just drop `<div *matNoDataRow>No data</div>` inside `<mat-table>`.
Though it still won't help hiding `<mat-paginator>` if you've got one

Comment: You can have a better colspan with: `<td [colSpan]="displayedColumns.length">`

Comment: Does anyone know why using `<mat-row>` and `<mat-cell>` doesn't work with the `*matNoDataRow` directive but using `<tr>` and `<td>` does?

Comment: You need to make use of ```<mat-table>``` instead of a ```<table>``` to use ```<mat-row>``` and ```<mat-cell>```.

Answer (score 23):

You can put it in the footer row this way:

Column definition:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="noRecord">
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>No records found.</td>
</ng-container>
```

Footer row definition:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="dataSource.data.length === 0">
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noRecord']"></tr>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: This looks like a very promising solution because the footer row should be styled nicely to match, but it's difficult to assemble from these pieces, would you please show the complete HTML template?

Comment: @chrisinmtown:Just put this inside e.g: 
<mat-table> 
<ng-container matColumnDef="noRecord">
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>No records found.</td>
</ng-container>
<ng-template [ngIf]="dataSource.data.length === 0">
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noRecord']"></tr>
</ng-template>
</mat-table>

Comment: I also tried this solution but it doesn't work for me. When I delete an object and the table becomes empty the row doesn't show up. When the I reload the page then it shows up, but while adding an object the row doesn't vanish. It's very strange. Can anyone provide a working exmaple for this?

Answer (score 19):

If you console.log dataSource, you will see the following:
[dataSource example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtr0s.png)

It is not the dataSource itself that is the array, but dataSource.data. dataSource is actually a class that has a property data that contains what you pass into MatTableDataSource (https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/table/table-data-source.ts) Therefore, this is what you should be using for your *ngIf statement.

```
<div *ngIf="dataSource.data.length === 0">
No Records Found!
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just in case if anyone is using filter then you need to check for `data.filteredData.length === 0`

Comment: this is not working for me! html fails to fetch inner .data property .data.length blows code.

even after this
      this.dataSource =  new MatTableDataSource();
      this.dataSource.data = [];

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to show error message in html

> 1st method using **If** method

```
<div *ngIf="dataSource.length">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >
  <ng-container matColumnDef="tache">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> tâche </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.tache}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="outil">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> outil </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.outil}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
  </mat-row>
</mat-table>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!dataSource.length">
No Record found
</div>
```

> 2nd Method Using **If else**

```
<div *ngIf="dataSource.length; else noRecord">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >
  <ng-container matColumnDef="tache">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> tâche </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.tache}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="outil">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> outil </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.outil}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
  </mat-row>
</mat-table>
</div>

<ng-template #noRecord>
 <div>
  No Record found
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [ngClass]="{'hide':!(listData!=null && listData.filteredData.length==0)}"></mat-footer-row>
```

I was able to solve the problem by doing this.
`hide` is a custom css

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [ngClass]="{'hide':!(listData!=null && listData.filteredData.length==0)}"></mat-footer-row>

Comment: great solution but rather than hiding <tr> you can make the array dynamic `matFooterRowDef="['noData']"` and add the column name in case only when you want to display the NOT FOUND message

Answer (score 5):

In your `component-name.component.html`:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="fullName">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Full Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.fullName}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        ...
        ...
        <ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
            <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
                No data.
            </mat-footer-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

        <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [ngClass]="{'hide':!(listData!=null && listData.data.length==0)}"></mat-footer-row>
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" [pageSize]="5" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

In your `style.scss` or `component-name.component.scss` define `.hide` class

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

and that's all :)

Comment: This works for me. I just changed to check by dataSource.filteredData.length

Answer (score 5):

> Step #0

In ts

```
  dataSource: any = new MatTableDataSource()
```

> Step #1

```
      <table [dataSource]="dataSource">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="nodata">
          <td mat-footer-row *matFooterCellDef [colSpan]="displayedColumns.length" 
          style="text-align: center;">No Data Available</td>
        </ng-container>

       <tr mat-footer-row 
         [hidden]="dataSource.data.length >0"
        *matFooterRowDef="['nodata']">
       </tr>

     </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

In newer Angular versions don't forget `datasource.data` if your datasource is of type `MatTableDataSource`.

**Example:**

In the TypeScript file:

```
// ...
datasource = new MatTableDataSource<object>([]);
// ...
```

And in the HTML file:

```
<div *ngIf="datasource.data.length > 0"> 
  <!--Show the table.-->
</div>

<div *ngIf="datasource.data.length === 0">
 <!--Show table is empty message. -->
</div>
```

Comment: it is failing for me. `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')`

Answer (score 2):

If anyone uses `filter` with `dataSource`, you should watch for `dataSource.filteredData.length`.

i.e.

```
if (this.dataSource.filteredData.length < 1) {
  this.presentDialog();
}
```

or

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="dataSource.filteredData.length < 1">
    // Your message here...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `*ngIf` directive to check if `dataSource` is not empty.

```
 <mat-table *ngIf="dataSource.length > 0" #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >
  <ng-container matColumnDef="tache">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> tâche </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.tache}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="outil">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> outil </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.outil}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
  </mat-row>
</mat-table>

<p *ngIf="dataSource.length === 0">No records found</p>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to post your `dataSource`?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition on your dataSource directly without having to access the data or its length:

```
<div *ngIf="!yourDataSource" class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">No data </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML hidden attribute to achieve same thing

```
<tr [hidden]="dataSource.data.length > 0" mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noRecord']" ></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as **PLPeeters** said If you are using ***Angluar Material >= 10*** or more, then you can show a message when no data matches the filter, by using the *matNoDataRow directive, which looks something like this :

```
 <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
  <td class="mat-cell" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
    No data matching the filter.
  </td>
</tr>
```

If you are using ***Angular Material <10*** Then You can use the following code to show data after filtering, if no data is available you can show the row with the text :

```
      <!-- No Data Found -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="noDataFound" >
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="7" [hidden]="dataSource?.filteredData?.length!=0">
          No records found 
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

In .ts file

```
if (this.dataSource.length == 0) {
    this.noDataMessage = true;
} else {
    this.noDataMessage = false;
}
```

In .html file

```
<div *ngIf="noDataMessage">
    <p>{{ 'label.DataNotAvailable' | translate }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the option to do this in the Footer, I have been able to do this by doing following steps in Angular 6/7/8:

1)  In your [ComponentName].component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceTable">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="columneName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.columnname}} </td>
            <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>
                <!-- Display a download button in the footer when data is available-->
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" 
*ngIf="dataSourceTable.data.length > 0">Download</button>
                <!--Below code is displayed when there is no data-->
                <a mat-button *ngIf="dataSourceTable.data.length === 0">No Data 
Found</a>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <!--Below Lines of code generates Header, Row and footer for your table  -->
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true;"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
        </tr>
        <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="noRecords">
  <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>
    No records found
  </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="!dataSource.filteredData.length ? ['noRecords'] : []" colspan="2"></tr>
```

Also note that it's possible you have to add a `<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>` for every row if you already use the footer.

Comment: Nice solution, but colspan should be set on the `<td>` element. You can add it with:
`<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef [colSpan]="displayedColumns.length">`.
Nevertheless, now the best approach is the one proposed by @rrr: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63185957/690691

Answer (score 0):

My solution does not alter the footer, and shows the message inside of the actual table by using CSS and adding a box `:before` the footer:

First some CSS:

```
td.no-content {
  padding-top: 7rem;
}

td.no-content:before {
  content: attr(data-empty-message);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3rem 0 3rem 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Then add the `no-content` class to the footer TD when nothing is showing:

```
<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef 
    [class.no-content]="dataSource.filteredData.length === 0" 
    data-empty-message="Nothing found..."
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a runtime error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" if the array was null.
Solved it by first checking the null value, and if true it does not proceed to the length test, thus not causing the error.
i.e.

```
<tr *ngFor="let category of _projectCategories">
        <td>
            {{ category.name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ category.description }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ category.group }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <i class="nc-icon" [class.nc-check-2]="category.active"
                [class.nc-simple-remove]="!category.active"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="(_projectCategories==null) || (_projectCategories.length == 0)">
        <td colspan="2">
            Project currently has no categories.
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your table add this

```
   <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
        <td class="mat-cell" colspan="9999">No Transactions yet!</td>
    </tr>
```